# Is this a common LCD display?

Tags: lcd, identification, display

I'd like to know if this LCD display is a common one like the HD44780. Sadly there is no model number on it, only the brand(?) "onv" or maybe it should be "auo" when you read it upside down. It's part of a car radio. It has a 40 pins connector.

connector:

[image]

whole display:

[image]

Comment: [A U Optronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AU_Optronics) is a popular manufacturer of displays and one of its markings is AUO.

Comment: http://www.displayalliance.com/storage/1-spec-sheets/A070FW03-V9.pdf (via TS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That display is almost assuredly a graphics display. That would make it MUCH different from a HD44780 style display that natively displays characters.

Enough information is not provided to determine if this display has a controller onboard that is capable of receiving the graphics display pixels and managing the refreshing of the screen to keep the display alive. Alternatively this display could be one of the type where a real time video signal needs to be fed to the display in order to keep the screen active. In this alternate mode the display would be working similar to a computer driven LCD monitor that requires a continuous feed of a VGA or DVI video signal to keep the screen active.

In either case be prepared for a fair amount of work to get the display going. Personally I would suggest that you begin work with something that you can get some decent information on it in order to figure out what it does and how you can "talk" to it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old but I just recently took apart a Kodak ESP 7 AiO printer and found a lcd just like this. Mine is a 3". The connector looks a little different but has the same amount of pins. It had a number printed on the back **59.03A13.001**.
When I googled that number I got a model number **A030DN01-V0**. I looked at the data sheets and everything looks pretty good. I havent thoroughly looked through it yet.

[Datasheet](http://www.beyondinfinite.com/lcd/Library/Auo/A030DN01-V0.pdf)
[Mirror](http://www.datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/A030DN01-V0.html)

[image: LCD:]

Answer (score 1):

they are used in Kodak printers but i have had no luck finding data sheets for those either...
ONV is actually AUO
as for model - going to there website helped a little but still i could not find my screen a "s501"
http://www.auo.com/?sn=149&lang=en-US&c=39

and you could perhaps follow something like this http://g3nius.org/lcd-controller/ to give you and idea on how to start using it